# How to reference an IBOutlet in an NSObject that is defined in a different NSObject

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In a Mac Cocoa program, I have an AppController NSObject which performs most app functions and utilizes a MainMenu.xib file to conduct most interaction with the user.

However, I would like to announce error conditions encountered in that AppController with a separate pop up window which has a text field in its window to display the error.

That text field in the separate pop up window is not recognized in the AppController.

Do I need to somehow make the pop up window's controller a delegate or should the AppController be a delegate of the pop up window controller?
Will that make the IBOutlet of the pop up's text field visible to the AppController?

Comment: You should add some code to your question to show what you are doing. That said if I follow your question correctly the answer he is probably that your `AppController` should have no direct access to your `PopupController`'s text field; rather your `AppController` should call a method on your `PopupController` passing in the message it wishes displayed and how that is achieved is the sole concern of the `PopupController`. (Look at `NSAlert`, there is a `messageText` property to set not an `NSTextField` to populate.) HTH

Comment: Ah yes, I can add a notification to send the error code to the popup window controller. Sometimes I go down rabbit holes and then can’t see other ways out. Guess that’s why these questions are helpful. Thank you very much. I didn’t think adding code here would be helpful, its pretty standard window controller stuff.